# Update a dependent field in R6 object when a parent field is updated

Tags: r, oop, r6

I'm new to R6 and object oriented programming, so i'm not sure the right way to even talk about dependencies between fields inside an object.

My objects have fields that are dependent on other fields inside the object.  I would like those dependent fields to automatically update when one of the inputs is updated.

I have figured out a manual way of doing this, but thought that there may be a better way. I played around with `active` fields but i could not get them to work.

This example should make it clear. I have an object `quad` that takes `width` and `height` and calculates `area`.  I would like `area` to be automatically updated when `width` or `height` are updated.

This seems to be one of the things that active fields are intended to achieve, but i couldn't make them work.

For the purpose of exposition i hacked to my goal by including a re-calculation line for `self$area` in the `set` method for each field.

How is this supposed to be done?

```
library(R6)
quad <- R6Class("quad", public =
                list(width = NULL,
                     height = NULL,
                     area = NULL,
                     initialize = function(width, height) {
                         self$width <- width
                         self$height <- height
                         self$area = self$width * self$height
                         self$greet()
                     },
                     set_width = function(W) {
                         self$width <- W
                         self$area = self$width * self$height #hack
                     }, 
                     set_height = function(H) {
                         self$height <- H
                         self$area = self$width * self$height #hack
                     }, 
                     greet = function() {
                         cat(paste0("your quad has area: ", self$area, ".\n"))
                     })
                )
#
> quad1 <- quad$new(5, 5)
your quad has area: 25.

> quad1$set_height(10)
> quad1$area
[1] 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An active binding is essentially a function that is invoked without needing to use `()`, so it looks like a regular field.

In the example below, `area` is an active binding and is computed each time you access it.

```
library(R6)
Quad <- R6Class(
  "Quad",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(width, height) {
      self$width <- width
      self$height <- height
    },
    width = NULL,
    height = NULL
  ),
  active = list(
    area = function() {
      self$width * self$height
    }
  )
)


q <- Quad$new(8, 3)
q$area
#> [1] 24

q$height <- 5
q$area
#> [1] 40
```

Comment: Thanks @wch.  The main point of the question was really the best way / how this is supposed to be done.  I would imagine that making `area` an active field may be expensive, as the calculation would be re-done each time we call `q$area`, even if `height` and `width` are unchanged?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. The cost of invoking a function in R is pretty small, so for most things I wouldn't worry about it. If you're accessing the `area` much more than `height`/`width`, then you can make `area` a normal value and make `height` and `width` active bindings that set the value of `area`. If performance is really a concern, I suggest benchmarking (with microbenchmark or bench) and profiling your code (with profvis).